# cannot call the function in smart contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle

i am try to call a method in solidity smart contract through angular app. but i unable to call the method. can someone please help me. this is the error i get in console

```
TypeError: this.contract.methods.hello is not a function
at CertificateContractService.<anonymous> (certificate-contract.service.ts:32)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:70)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39699)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
at zone-evergreen.js:855
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
```

---

### Smart contract

```
contract CertificateList {

    function hello() external pure returns (string memory )  {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

### Angular service

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import {WEB3} from './WEB3';

declare let require: any;
declare let window: any;


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CertificateContractService {
  private abi: any;
  private address = '0xb0fFD3498B219ad2A62Eb98fEDE591265b3C3B67';
  private contract;
  private accounts: string[];

  constructor(@Inject(WEB3) private web3: Web3) {
    this.init().then(res => {
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }

  private async init() {
    this.abi = require('../assets/abi/CertificateList.json');
    // await this.web3.currentProvider.enable();
    this.accounts = await this.web3.eth.getAccounts();

    this.contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(this.abi, this.address, {gas: 1000000, gasPrice: '10000000000000'});

    this.contract.methods.hello().send()
      .then(receipt => {
        console.log(receipt);
      }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
}
```

### Provider

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import Web3 from 'web3';

export const WEB3 = new InjectionToken<Web3>('web3', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => {
    try {
      window['ethereum'].autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;
      const provider = ('ethereum' in window) ? window['ethereum'] : Web3['givenProvider'];
      return new Web3(provider);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying Mist or MetaMask!');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `../assets/abi/CertificateList.json` contains a valid abi exclusively. If you acquired this file by executing `truffle compile` or `solc CertificateList.sol` directly, you have to extract the abi from the json file.

```js
var contractJson = require('../assets/abi/CertificateList.json');
this.abi = contractJson['abi'];
```

Also, you can not use `methods.hello.send` on a pure function. The send method can be called only on functions that modify the contract's state, i.e. *payable* or *unspecified* functions. To invoke *pure* or *view* functions, the `call` method should be used. For more information see [web3.eth.Contract](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call).

```js
this.contract.methods.hello().call()
  .then(receipt => {
    console.log(receipt);
  }).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```